# GTFS route planner

Tags: python, gtfs

I am in the process of creating an application which can tell people when a bus leaves from a certain stop and I would like to add route planning to it.

I need a way to plan routes from a stop to another in a couple of seconds. I'm getting my data from a GTFS file parsed to SQLite

I have looked at [OpenTripPlanner](http://www.opentripplanner.org/) and [GraphServer](http://graphserver.github.io/graphserver/), but I couldn't find an API which can plan routes and give those routes back in a JSON or some other format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have overlooked in the OpenTripPlanner documentation that it does give you an option to give a JSON or XML response.

Have a look at this specific section: http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/0.20.0/json_Response.html

Comment: For this I need to set up a webserver with OpenTripPlanner?

Comment: Absolutely yes. It’s fairly easy, although it’s a bit RAM consuming (the minimum is 4Gb I think)